# Motorola 68000 Assembly

Tags: assembly, motorola, 68000

I got a simple question. No idea where to start.  I need a simple math calculation (+,_,*,/) to output at least 2 digits.

Example:  1+2=03

```
move #1,D0
move #2,D1
add.l D0,D1
```

the above needs to output a 03. ...it outputs a 3.

I've gotta display the 0, but the normal add instruction does not do this.  How does one even approach this?  i'm lost. ?? TY.

Comment: The above does not output anything. Value `3` is purely abstract entity. The binary-encoding-by-electricity-current in the register `d0` can be interpreted as value `3` (two least significant bits are set to "1", others to "0", if you take value of bit *i* as 2^i), but that's not true mathematical abstract `3`, just an imperfect "mirror reflection" projected into electricity current. Meanwhile mankind glyph writing "3" is neither the value `3` itself, again just imperfect projection into font glyphs, using decimal encoding. If you want "03" from value 3, output two characters (3 div/mod 10).

Comment: to rephrase my first comment: the value from `add` is OK. What you need is formatter code... like in C `printf("%d", 3)` vs `printf("%02d", 3)`, both will display the same value `3`, but first will output single character `'3'`, second will output two characters, `'0'` and `'3'`. Depending what you use to output the value (some library?), it may already contain some formatting code.

Comment: so if i put printf("%02d, 3)" in a disassembler i should get my answer?? ok, ty for hint.  I'll try it.,    keep the advice coming :)

Comment: I tried it..   printf("02d"3) prints 033.  closer but no beans

Comment: Printf("%02d",3)    THANKS GUY!!!  got my disassembled code

Answer (score 1):

Answer posted above

Disassemble printf("%02d",3) in a 68k dissembler (IDE68k)